# Proving a polynomial splits over a certain field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

> If $K$ is the splitting field of $f\in F[x]$, and $g\in F[x]$ is irreducible and has a root in $K$, prove that $g$ splits over $K$.

My proof (which I don't think is correct) is as follows:
Let $a\in K$ be a root of $g$. As $g(a)=0$, by the division theorem for polynomials $\exists h\in F[x]$ such that $g(x) = (x-a)h(x)$, where $\deg(h)=\deg(g) - 1$. We will prove by induction.

If $\deg(g) = 2$, then $g(x) = (x-a)(x-b)$ where $a,b\in K$. So the base case holds.
Now assume that the proposition is true for $\forall g\in F[x]$ such that $\deg(g) = n$. 
If $\deg(g) = n+1$, then $g(x) = (x-a)h(x)$ where $\deg(h) = n$. As $\deg(h) = n$ we see that $h$ splits over $K$ and therefore so does $g$. So by induction we are done.

I feel like even though $\deg(h) = n$, I can't assume that $h$ automatically splits over $K$ because $a$ is not necessarily a root of $h$. Any help or tips appreciated!

Comment: Use \deg instead of the complicated \operatorname{deg}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it using the normality condition, because automorphisms of a field over its algebraic closure permute the roots of a generator, you can see that if $K$ is the splitting field for $f$ then $K= F(\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n)$ with $\alpha_i$ the roots of $f$. But then as $F(\beta)$ with $\beta$ a root of $g$ is a subfield of $K$, we see that there is an injection

$$E = F[x]/(g(x))\to K$$

so we may consider $F\subseteq E\subseteq K$. But then any automorphism of $E/F$ extends to an automorphism of $K/F$, and vice versa for restriction. But then as all automorphisms of $E/F$ are realized by automorphisms of $K/F$ (when restricted to $E$) and these automorphisms are exactly those that permute the roots (transitively since $g$ is irreducible) all roots of $g$ are just $\varphi(\beta)$ for some $\varphi: K\to K$ fixing $F$, i.e. an automorphism of $K/F$. Since all the roots are in $K$, $g$ splits in $K[x]$ by definition.